# Who will decide commentary team in cricket

Tags: cricket, media

During international cricket matches who will decide the commentary panel?

Is there any eligibility criteria for that?

When will they announce the list of commentators for the particular series?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about TV, not sport

Comment: @TrueDub Then how about questions found under the [`media`](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/media) tag? Not saying I disagree here, but saying I want to be consistent with the handling of these "media" questions.

Comment: @edmastermind29 I didn't notice that tag, and on investigation this question seems to fit the tag perfectly. I still don't think it's relevant on a sports stack exchange site, but that's a different issue - as things stand this question is ok. I've retracted my close vote.

Comment: broadcaster I think. In my opinion the broadcaster has rights to chose the commentators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> During international cricket matches who will decide the commentary panel?

The broadcaster.

> Is there any eligibility criteria for that?

No.

> When will they announce the list of commentators for the particular series?

When they feel like it.

Comment: Unless it's in India, then it's the BCCI who decides the panel and the list.